# Нет интернет соединения на OC Linux

Tags: linux

Как видно нет возможности подключить Wi-Fi соединение, ноутбук не поддерживает подключение на прямую через кабель

[image]

Подскажите в чем проблема и как ее устранить, подалуйста?
Проблема не в дистрибутиве, пробовал как Кали так и Убунту

Comment: Возможно, ваше Wi-Fi устройство не поддерживается линуксом? А даже если поддерживается, то, возможно, нужно каким-то чудом найти, скачать и установить драйвер

Comment: На виртуалке все работает, а на винде так подавно.
Нужен вывод lspci -nk -v и lsusb -t ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключи телефон кабелем к компьютеру и в настройках поставь режим модема USB.
Найди в настройках убунты приложение "Программы и обновления" - там вкладка дополнительные драйвера. Если найдет - установи что попросит, если нет - устанавливай для начала следующие пакеты:

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/linux-firmware
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/linux-wlan-ng-firmware
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/firmware-b43-installer
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/firmware-ath9k-htc